# Как сделать расчет дистанции между двумя улицами в городе (яндекс.карты)?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Решил я изучить API яндекс карт и для повышения своих знаний научиться определять дистанцию между двумя адресами в городе при помощи яндекс.карт.
Если быть честным, у меня получилось не очень здорово.
На самом деле я не далеко ушел от примера из [яндекс](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_data_access).
Вопрос, может кто-то имеет опыт работы с этим API и может показать как правильно сделать расчет такого расстояния? Например: Минск, ул. Волгоградская 25 - Минск, ул. Грицевца 4.
Может у кого-то есть примеры похожих скриптов?

Comment: Тогда уж тут не между улицами, как таковыми, а между конкретными точками на карте.

Comment: @edem я хотел сделать форму. В одну строку вписываем одну улицу, в другую другую - жмем вводи и получаем дистанцию между ними.